# Macro for moving hat symbol up

Tags: math-mode, positioning, accents, mathpazo

I use mathpazo font package and I think the hat symbol is too low. Can I make a macro to change behavior of all my hats?

This question has a good example, but I don't want to have to retype all of my hats:

[Can I move the hat symbol vertically upwards?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174122/can-i-move-the-hat-symbol-vertically-upwards/174127#174127)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I move the hat symbol vertically upwards?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174122/can-i-move-the-hat-symbol-vertically-upwards)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I use `stackengine` to add a stacking gap on the argument of `\hat`.  I also use `scalerel` package to preserve the math style, and to express the stacking gap, `.3\LMpt`, in terms of a unit that scales with the math style (as an argument to `\ThisStyle{}`, `\LMpt` is a scalable version of 1pt, that will scale with smaller math styles).

The hat kerning is lost, when I wrap the argument in an `\addstackgap`, so I re-add kerning to the hat, proportional to the height of the glyph, using `\slantfactor` = `.2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\slantfactor{.2}
\let\svhat\hat
\def\hat#1{%
  \ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\kern\slantfactor\ht0%
  \svhat{\addstackgap[.3\LMpt]{$\kern-\slantfactor\ht0\SavedStyle#1$}}}}
\begin{document}
$\svhat{x}\svhat{P}$ (original)

$\hat{x} \hat{P} \scriptstyle \hat{x} \hat{P} \scriptscriptstyle \hat{x} \hat{P}$
(revised)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great answer, I don't have stackengine.sty on my windows latex install and installing packages manually seems to be quite a headache that I have yet to try (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows). Any solution that does not require stackengine?

Comment: @Benjamin The package can be downloaded from http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine.  If you just place the .sty file in your working directory, all should work.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `mathpazo` package, which is (a) quite old and (b) well known for having various font metric problems, you could use the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages. These are derived from the `mathpazo` package but have much better font metrics. In particular, these packages produce well-spaced hat symbols. If you use these packages instead of `mathpazo` -- and I can honestly not think of a good reason for continuing to use `mathpazo` if `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` are available on your system -- there's simply no need to manually correct/improve the spacing of the stacked hat symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxmath,newpxtext}
\begin{document}
$\hat{u}$ $\hat{U}$
\end{document}
```

For comparison, here are the same two symbols with the `mathpazo` package loaded instead of `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`:

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! I accepted @Steven's answer since he directly answered my question (for anyone in the future looking to change hat height, regardless of font used). I will probably use this solution though.