# Alternative of `\rule` in ConTeXt for lifting `\hat` slightly up

Tags: context, kerning

In ConTeXt, I want to lift a `\hat` slightly up, since `\hat` is too low and touches the variable.
Now, [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174122/can-i-move-the-hat-symbol-vertically-upwards) is exactly what I want.
It suggests:

```
\hat{\rule{0ex}{1.2ex}\mkern-3mu x}_{t+1}
```

However, ConTeXt seemingly doesn't recognize `\rule`.
I don't understand the nature of `\rule`, and I can't find explanation in *The TEXbook* nor in *TEX for the Impatient*.
Is `\rule` a LaTeX function?
Where can I find the function definition, and how can I implement it using (perhaps) plain TEX and ConTeXt functions?
Or are there other ways to achieve the result?

Comment: Which font are you using? I think that it should be possible to adjust the "height" of x using a font goodie file.

Comment: @Aditya TeX Gyre Pagella Math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ConTeXt the command is named `\blackrule` instead of `\rule`.  In contrast to LaTeX's `\rule` it follows the intuitive key-value syntax.

```
\starttext

$\hat{x}_{t+1}$
$\hat{\blackrule[width=0ex,height=1.2ex]\mkern-3mu x}_{t+1}$

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`\vphantom` works in ConTeXt. You just need to use a character that has the height you want. In the example, `<` is used since it is slightly taller than `x`.

```
\define[1]\hihat{\hat{\vphantom{<}#1}}

\starttext

$\hat{x}_{t+1}\hihat{x}_{t+1}$

\stoptext
```